# trouble maker when I write email or username

Tags: xiaomi, firefox-for-android, text-prediction

When I want to write email or username, or when I search for topics e.g. on stack overflow, when I begin to write, I see immediately on the screen things I wrote in the past and sometimes, despite that I write something else, the previous typings replace them. It appens when I write to buy on Amazon or when I want to buy an airline ticket, when I want to write tags on a stack overflow site.

How can I neutralize this "help"…?

I'm browsing with Firefox, with a Google keyboard, my phone is a mi Max 3 working with Android 8.1.

Comment: Perhaps is it linked with automatic remembering passwords or equivalent function of the browser

Comment: Please check the Firefox settings. There's a way to clear personal data, where you can chose which to clear and which to keep. You most likely want to clear form data (and maybe cookies as well, to get rid of some tracking beacons while on it). As I don't use Firefox on mobile, I cannot tell you where exactly that is.

Comment: I'll try thanks

Comment: And did you succeed?

Comment: No, sorry.  I need to find time to think about